# How to use a custom layout as a view in a Table Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a layout which I want to use as elements in a TableLayout. I have tried to inflate the layout as views, and then add them into TabelRow. For some reason it doesn't work and I haven't been able to figure out why, or how to solve it.

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        TableLayout sudokuGrid = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.sudokuGrid);
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        View cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, null);
        tableRow.addView(cell);
        sudokuGrid.addView(tableRow);
```

Comment: I believe the cell and TableRow has no param telling it, what is the height and width constraint it

Comment: Could you post the error that you get from the logcat?